# oracle query to check not exists in other table

Tags: database, oracle

I have following query:

```
select vw.CONFERENCEID, alert.ALERTID, del.CHANNELID, del.DOCUMENTTEMPLATEID,
       vw.starttime, vw.CONFERENCEID, alert.ALERTATTRIBUTEID,
       alert.ALERTCATEGORYID, alert.ATTACHMENT, alert.ATTACHMENTLOCATION,
       alert.ATTACHMENTNAME
  from TBLMCONFERENCE vw,
       TBLMSYSTEMALERTS alert,
       TBLMALERTDELIVERYREL del,
       tblmstandardmaster sm 
 WHERE alert.Alertid = del.alertid
   and sm.masterid = del.CHANNELID
   and alert.SYSTEMGENERATED = 'N'
   and alert.alertid not in (
       select sent.ALERTID
         from TBLMSENTALERTHISTORY sent
        where sent.REFACCOUNTID = vw.conferenceid
          and sent.ALERTID = alert.ALERTID
          and sent.CHANNELID = del.CHANNELID
          and sent.RESETFLAG = 'N')
```

I am getting records even when a matching record exists in `TBLMSENTALERTHISTORY` table.

Is there anything wrong in this query?

Comment: Have you tried firing the inner query and checking to see that the alertid is present in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are getting data, maybe you could build a small example with a couple of tables and inserts.

However, I can point that your use of the `NOT IN` operator is not standard: in most cases you should not join the subquery to the main query with `IN` and `NOT IN` operators (it is redundant). Instead you would write:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TBLMCONFERENCE vw,
       TBLMSYSTEMALERTS alert,
       TBLMALERTDELIVERYREL del,
       tblmstandardmaster sm
 WHERE alert.Alertid = del.alertid
   AND sm.masterid = del.CHANNELID
   AND alert.SYSTEMGENERATED = 'N'
   AND (alert.alertid, del.CHANNELID, vw.conferenceid)
       NOT IN (SELECT sent.ALERTID, sent.CHANNELID, sent.conferenceid
                 FROM TBLMSENTALERTHISTORY sent
                WHERE sent.RESETFLAG = 'N')
```

In your case you could use your subquery directly with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TBLMCONFERENCE vw,
       TBLMSYSTEMALERTS alert,
       TBLMALERTDELIVERYREL del,
       tblmstandardmaster sm
 WHERE alert.Alertid = del.alertid
   AND sm.masterid = del.CHANNELID
   AND alert.SYSTEMGENERATED = 'N'
   AND NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT sent.ALERTID
             FROM TBLMSENTALERTHISTORY sent
            WHERE sent.REFACCOUNTID = vw.conferenceid
              AND sent.ALERTID = alert.ALERTID
              AND sent.CHANNELID = del.CHANNELID
              AND sent.RESETFLAG = 'N')
```

Note that in general `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` are not equivalent, [because of NULLs](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3aNO%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:442029737684).